# How to create/maintain a basic associative array/hash with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hash, associative-array

I am recording acceleration data for the x-axis, so I have two values coming in - the x value, and the epoch time of the acceleration event. I want to store these as a hash, where the epoch time is the key and x-value is the value.

I created an array:

```
var arrX = new Array();
```

How can I add to it? Like this?

```
arrX[acceleration.timestamp] = acceleration.x
```

Comment: Is the timestamp a raw number?

Comment: Yes, it's a raw number like "14112123245556" so is the x value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an object, which [can serve as a sort of "associative array"](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) for this application. An object will provide support for the arbitrary, non-sequential keys that you mentioned, where an array would not.

```
var arrX = {};

arrX[acceleration.timestamp] = acceleration.x;
```

More information:

- [Javascript Does Not Support Associative Arrays](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX9)
- [MDN: Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description), par. 2

Comment: *"...where an array would not"* That's not exactly correct. An Array would offer the same support an Object would since an Array is a type of Object. It's just that the `Array.prototype` methods will only work with numeric indices. Also an Array doesn't require that the indices are sequential.

Comment: Sure, you could use an array for the job, but I think we can agree it's definitely not the most fitting data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but without the array. Just use an object like this

```
var values = {};
values[acceleration.timestamp] = acceleration.x;
```

because if you do something like this

```
var x = [];
x[1555] = 500;
```

you will create an array of 1556 elemenets, with all elements but the 1555 set to undefined

Comment: Actually the `x[1555]` example sets `x.length` to 1556 because `.length` is always 1 higher than the highest assigned index, but it doesn't actually create any of the other elements. It's a subtle difference, but using the `in` operator or `.hasOwnProperty()` you can tell whether a particular index has been explicitly assigned `undefined` or just never assigned a value. The [`Array.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) also skips over array indexes never assigned a value...

Comment: *"...will create an array of 1556 elemenets"* No it won't. It'll create an Array with one element, but the `.length` property set at `1557`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript if you need an associative array, you use an object:

```
var hash1 = {}; // declare
hash1.first = 'abc'; // set property first to a string
hash1['second'] = 'def'; // set property second to a string

var t = 'third';
hash1[t] = 'ghi'; // set property third to a string

hash1.forth = {a:1, b: 'abc'}; // set property forth to be an object / hash
                               // with 2 properties

alert (hash1.forth.a); // will alert with 1
```